# class active CSS issue in angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have separate component of a tile in which i show all the list of data so when i click the tile it should show active class CSS in particular tile but now where ever i click it shows active class in all tiles.

```html
div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 12px" *ngIf="!loading">  
    <div class="container-fluid " *ngIf="!done"> 
      <adm-tile 
      [heading]='heading'
      [orderno]='stock.id'
      [time]='stock.created_at'
      [category]='stock.request_category.name'
      [status_type]='getStatus(stock.status)'
      [name]='stock.requester.first_name'
      [branch]='stock.to_department.name'
      [date]='stock.delivery_date'
      [priority]='stock.priority'
      [index_no] = 'i'
      [data]= 'stock'
      [title]="'Requested To'"
      [title1] = "'From'"
      (selected)="onButton06($event)" 
 *ngFor="let stock of stock_list ; let i = index" ></adm-tile>


 <div class="wrapper-card __list-card --small-card" style="margin-top:-5px"  (click)="button01()" [class.active-border-selection]="index_no === selectedIndex1">
    <div class="media">
           <div class="media-body">
               <div class="rowa split" style="position: relative">
                 <div class="col-6" style="position: relative">
                     <div > 
                        <div  style="height: 19px;overflow: hidden !important;">
                            <label class=" bold2">{{heading}}</label><span class="bold2">:#{{orderno}} </span>
                             <span class="bold2 desktop"> - {{your_date | timeAgo}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div style="height: 22px">
                            <label class="bold3 ">{{category}}</label>
                        </div>
                     </div>
             
                 </div>
             </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
   button01() {
    this.selectedIndex1 = this.index_no;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Whenever `onButton06()` is triggered try to assign a boolean variable to it such as `isActive` and pass it via a service or a @Input and use that value to show active class in `adm-title`. One more thing, instead of using these many inputs, I would suggested you to use a service or a single input object to send data.

Comment: @nitin9nair i am passing index of ngfor from parent component to child to assign to particular tile still same issue so how to assign a variable is-active in button6 that is in child area and the active class is in child component.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for this issue, so that i can understand this issue and help you better?

Comment: @nitin9nair please the stackbliz of the issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-components-step-2wzhvt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpayroll%2Fpayroll-search.component.ts

Comment: go the solution for the issue with https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-components-step-2wzhvt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhr-files%2Fhr-files-search.component.ts

Comment: check my answer and also the stackblitz solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question for only one button or card to be active at one time, check below code. You need to set active in the parent component only not in child as all child are independent components.

**Parent Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'payroll-search',
  template: `
    <div  *ngFor="let stock of stock_list ; let i = index" >
     <hr-files-search
     style="position: relative; display:block"
     (sendIndex)="getIndex($event)"
     [class.active-border-selection]="i == selectedIndex"
     [index_no] = 'i'
     ></hr-files-search>
    </div>
  `
})
export class PayrollSearchComponent {
  stock_list = [1,2,3,4,4,5];
  public selectedIndex: number;

  public getIndex(event) {
    this.selectedIndex = event;
  }
}
```

**Child component**

```
import { Component, Input , OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hr-files-search',
  template: `
    <div class="card" (click)="button01(index_no)">
      <div class="card-content">
      <h6>hello</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class HrFilesSearchComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() index_no: any;
    @Output() sendIndex = new EventEmitter();
 ngOnInit() {

  }
  selectedIndex1;
  button01(index) {
    this.sendIndex.emit(index);
  }
}
```

Here is the [stackblitz solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-components-step-b4qvhs).